# how to increase vm heap sizein android if -Xmx is failed to increase?

Tags: android, jvm

i am using android studio In  that there will be a simple hello world program I am trying to run  AVD manger but it will give me following error:

> Could not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size
>   1536M too big, reduced to 896M

how to solve these?
how to run AVD manager?

Comment: can you put whole error

Answer (score 0):

1. You click run app
2. Click on Create New Emulator
3. Choose a device then click "clone device"
4. At memory field: you can set 896M.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

From Android studio open **Windows** --> **Select Android Virtual Device Manager** --> **Choose your device** --> **Click Edit button** -->**Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb in the Memory Options**-->**Save and run the emulator it will work**

Else you may use Genymotion Android Vm: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download